# Execute Ansible task on different hosts

Tags: ansible

I have a created a role, where I have defined all ansible tasks. Also I have host A and host B in the inventory. Is it possible to execute 90% of task on host A and 10% of task on host B? My Ansible controller is host C.

Comment: What do you mean by 90% of the tasks on host A and 10 on host B?

Comment: I am deploying stack on host A and I want to execute post configuration scripts on host B. Those script should be pushed from ansible controller(host C) or from host A to host B. but i am not sure how this can be achieved.

Comment: However, I managed  to push the scripts by fetching to host C, and using "delegate_to" to scp on host B, but not able to execute those scripts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first way I can think to do this is with conditionals based on inventory.

Create a group in inventory for A, and a group for B. I will call these group_A and group_B

```
# inventory
[group_A]
192.168.1.20

[group_B]
192.168.1.30
```

Then use conditionals on your tasks

```
- name: run this on A
  debug: msg="this runs only on A
  when: "'group_A' in {{group_names}}"

- name: run this on B
  debug: msg="this runs only on B
  when: "'group_B' in {{group_names}}"
```

Depending on how many tasks you have, it may be too much to put a conditional on every task, so you can use conditionals on includes, like so:

file structure:

```
-tasks
|- main.yml
|- A_tasks.yml
|- B_tasks.yml
```

main.yml:

```
- include: A_tasks.yml
  when: "'group_A' in {{group_names}}"
- include: B_tasks.yml
  when: "'group_B' in {{group_names}}"
```

A_tasks.yml:

```
- name: run on A
  debug: msg="this only runs on A"
```

B_tasks.yml:

```
- name: run on B
  debug: msg="this only runs on B"
```

Comment: This may have worked correctly in older versions of Ansible, but at least as of version 2.4.2.0 the conditional should be `when: "'group_A' in group_names"`.

Answer (score 16):

If you're splitting all of the tasks in one role between two different hosts, then neither of those hosts really has that role, do they?  I'd say it's an abuse of the role system to congregate all of those tasks into one role when you really have two.

What happens if you have multiple host As?  What about multiple host Bs?

It seems to me you don't actually want to use a role here - you want to use just a plain ol' playbook.

```
- hosts: A
  tasks:
    [...]

- hosts: B
  tasks:
    [...]
```

Playbooks are for defining a series of actions in a particular order, and your "do this stuff on B only after doing this stuff on A" is that.

Comment: I would tend to agree, but you could theoretically have a role designed to set up a Hadoop cluster, and you would need different tasks running on master and slaves. This goes beyond configuration management into infrastructure deployment, but it's supported in Ansible.

Comment: Exactly, I have the same requirements trying to set up a master / slave cluster (not Hadoop, as the concept is universal).

Comment: I'm facing the same question, should I use a role or just a playbook. The simplest sample is to upgrade packages. Depending on the distro, the strategy is different. I have my debian and my alpine boxes in different groups, so a playbook should serve me well. But as soon as I want to require a playbook to also have all packages up2date, I would benefit from a role I could just refer. I wonder if a role that contains several upgrade strategies depending on the distro is a fine approach.

Comment: @MillerGeek I did some more research. It seems you can also simply import another playbook, so I think Xiong isn't wrong here. A playbook could also just install one software and another playbook could import multiple playbooks. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html so a role can really do only one thing to all the affected hosts.